# Kill python interpeter in linux from the terminal

Tags: python, linux, terminal, command

I want to kill python interpeter - The intention is that all the python files that are running in this moment will stop (without any informantion about this files).
obviously the processes should be closed.

Any idea as delete files in python or destroy the interpeter is ok :D (I am working with virtual machine).
I need it from the terminal because i write c code and i use linux commands...
Hope for help

Answer (score 140):

```
pkill -9 python
```

should kill any running python process.

Comment: if the process name changed ?(from python to other name)

Comment: You can also be more selective per Python script with: https://stackoverflow.com/a/34239260/895245

Comment: really handy when using multiprocessing

Comment: @LorenzoBaracchi Can you explain what is the `-9` doing? I could not find it..

Comment: `-9` sets the signal to `SIGKILL`

Others include:

SIGHUP `-1` Hangup.
SIGINT `-2` Interrupt from keyboard.
SIGKILL `-9` Kill signal.
SIGTERM`-15` Termination signal.
SIGSTOP `-17, -19, -23` Stop the process.

Comment: luckly this doesn't the ones run by root...:)

Comment: @lorenzo-barrachi : this should be explained better, whether only current user processes are killed, or any one other than root user?

Answer (score 43):

There's a rather crude way of doing this, but be careful because first, this relies on python interpreter process identifying themselves as *python*, and second, it has the concomitant effect of also killing any other processes identified by that name.

In short, you can kill all python interpreters by typing this into your shell (make sure you read the caveats above!):

```
ps aux | grep python | grep -v "grep python" | awk '{print $2}' | xargs kill -9
```

To break this down, this is how it works. The first bit, `ps aux | grep python | grep -v "grep python"`, gets the list of all processes calling themselves python, with the grep -v making sure that the grep command you just ran isn't also included in the output. Next, we use awk to get the second column of the output, which has the process ID's. Finally, these processes are all (rather unceremoniously) killed by supplying each of them with `kill -9`.

Comment: You could change the third pipe section to grep -v "grep" to ignore any greps in the ps aux output. This makes the command more generic so one can change the second pipe section without worrying about changing the third. ps aux | grep "python -u" | grep -v "grep" | awk '{print $2}' | xargs kill -9

Answer (score 25):

**`pkill` with script path**

```
pkill -9 -f path/to/my_script.py
```

is a short and selective method that is more likely to only kill the interpreter running a given script.

See also: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/31107/linux-kill-process-based-on-arguments

Answer (score 20):

You can try the [killall](http://linux.die.net/man/1/killall) command:

`killall python`

Answer (score 11):

`pgrep -f <your process name> | xargs kill -9`

This will kill the your process service.
In my case it is

`pgrep -f python | xargs kill -9`

Answer (score 7):

`pgrep -f youAppFile.py | xargs kill -9`

`pgrep` returns the PID of the specific file will only kill the specific application.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to show the name of processes and kill them by the command of the kill, I recommended using this script to kill all python3 running process and set your ram memory free :

```
ps auxww | grep 'python3' | awk '{print $2}' | xargs kill -9
```

Answer (score 1):

I have seen the `pkill` command as the top answer. While that is all great, I still try to tread carefully (since, I might be risking my machine whilst killing processes) and follow the below approach:

First list all the python processes using:

```
$ ps -ef | grep python
```

Just to have a look at what root user processes were running beforehand and to cross-check later, if they are still running (after I'm done! :D)

then using `pgrep` as :

```
$ pgrep -u <username> python -d ' ' #this gets me all the python processes running for user username

# eg output:
11265 11457 11722 11723 11724 11725
```

And finally, I **kill** these processes by using the `kill` command after cross-checking with the output of `ps -ef| ...`

```
kill -9 PID1 PID2 PID3 ... 

# example 
kill -9 11265 11457 11722 11723 11724 11725
```

> Also, we can cross check the root PIDs by using :

```
pgrep -u root python -d ' '
```

and verifying with the output from `ps -ef| ...`

Answer (score 0):

to kill python script while using ubuntu 20.04.2 intead of <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd> just push together

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>D</kbd>