# How to display list of running processes Python?

Tags: python, linux, centos

How to display list of running processes Python with full name and active status?

I tried this command: `pgrep -lf python`

Comment: just in case you are trying to kill the user's jobs (not roots) that are running pythong this helped me: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18428750/kill-python-interpeter-in-linux-from-the-terminal/18428847 `pkill -9 python`

Answer (score 141, accepted):

Try this command:

```
ps -ef | grep python
```

`ps` stands for `process status`

Comment: Thank you, one comment, how to display full path to running file(process)?

Comment: how is this different from `ps -aux | grep python`?

Comment: @CharlieParker Please look at the `ps` man page to see the difference, more specifically at the examples secion here: https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/ps.1.html#EXAMPLES

Comment: `ps -ef | grep [p]ython`

Answer (score 19):

ps -aux will give all process grep python

```
ps -aux | grep python
```

Comment: You don't need a dash before `aux`, just `ps aux`.

Comment: how is this different from `ps -ef | grep python`?

Answer (score 14):

You could also setup a "watch" in a separate window to constantly monitor Python processes as you run a script: `watch -n 1 "ps u -C python3"`. Particularly useful when developing with multiprocessing.

Answer (score 3):

View 1 shows me all threads of python running, I use this for checking for memory leaks:

### View 1

```bash
ps -ef | grep [P]ython


#  502 14537 14484   0  5:47PM ttys000    0:00.58 /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/Resources/Python.app/Contents/MacOS/Python
#  502 14940 14484   0  5:57PM ttys000    0:00.55 /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/Resources/Python.app/Contents/MacOS/Python
```

### View 2

```bash
ps -ef | grep python


#  502 14950 14484   0  5:58PM ttys000    0:00.00 grep python
```

### View 3

```
ps aux | grep python


# jayrizzo         14957   0.0  0.0 34132060    896 s000  S+    5:58PM   0:00.00 grep python
```

All 3 variations provide slightly different results.

Answer (score 0):

Try this command

```
ps -ef | grep python
```

ps stands for `process status`